# Forecasting: choosing the sample split between "in-sample" and "out-of-sample" data

Tags: time-series, forecasting, out-of-sample, in-sample

**Goals:**

- Given approximately 11 years of time series data, to determine how much of this data should be reserved for `in-sample` and `out-of-sample` evaluation when using the data in the development of a forecasting system
- To become familiar with any potential techniques, if any, that can be used to determine an `in-sample` and `out-of-sample` "split" to reduce the likelihood of the `over-fitting` modelling error

**Details:**

As observable from the chart below, the `time-series` data spans from March 2012 to October 2023. During this approximate 11.5 year period, it seems that there are various data trend directions/ characteristics. For example:

- 2012 to 2014: up-trending
- 2014 to 2016: down-trending
- 2016 to 2018: sideways-moving
- 2020 onward: substantial up-trending, volatile

Additionally, the time-series data was likely sensitive to real-world inputs including the effects of the `COVID-19` pandemic occurring from the end of 2019 onward which were not present earlier on in the sample, and fluctuations in the health of the global economy throughout.

It seems that some approaches involve simply splitting the data *50:50* which would mean that the forecasting system is built and optimized on the first half of the historical data, and then its performance is tested without making any changes on the second half of the data. Others, [as seen at this page](https://alvarezquanttrading.com/blog/in-sample-and-out-of-sample-testing/), suggest potential approaches which include a 50:50 or 30:70 split, or even reserving the oldest data for the out-of-sample period.
[image]

**Questions:**

**Q1:** Based on the characteristics of the time series data seen in the above chart (i.e. various periods of up/down/sideways trending periods), are there any ways that this data could be divided so as to produce an appropriate dataset for developing the system before testing its performance, or would a 50:50 split be sufficient?

**Q2.** Are there any techniques that would help in determining an appropriate sample split, or is this very much a discretionary process that is unique to each set of sample data?

**Resources consulted before asking this question:**

1. [link 1](https://rady.ucsd.edu/_files/faculty-research/timmermann/samplesplitmining2012_feb07.pdf)
2. [link 2](https://www.kaggle.com/code/cworsnup/backtesting-cross-validation-for-timeseries)
3. [link 3](https://developers.google.com/machine-learning/data-prep/construct/sampling-splitting/example)
4. [link 4](https://www.eui.eu/Documents/DepartmentsCentres/Economics/Researchandteaching/Conferences/TSEConference-NewDevelopmentsinTimeSeries/Hansen.pdf)
5. [link 5](https://www.techtarget.com/searchenterpriseai/definition/data-splitting)
6. [link 6](https://www.researchgate.net/post/How_do_you_define_your_out-of-sample_size_eg_15_of_entire_data_for_variety_of_data_frequencies_eg_monthly)